# What is the best practice to read/write to HSQL from a client browser?

Tags: java, tomcat, hsqldb

I am running `HSQL` which is located on a shared drive. This is a managed network. I have to run a servlet using `Tomcat`. The users are reading and writing to  `HSQL` through a browser (servelet by Tomcat).

This works fine, but I have to run both `HSQL` and `Tomcat` as two separate programms from my computer. Is this the right way ? Is there any better option ? What is the best practice of serving html pages in a managed network ?

Comment: Just as a fair warning, whenever your question contains "_What is the best ..._" it usually means the answer will be opinion based and your question will be closed as such.

Answer (score 1):

Updating a cache is always nightmare.
That's why in some systems some are using a enterprise bus systems. Like getting from database you can connect to a data provider (could be a webservice, any service). This service can have event manager to process all affects of users and standalone application then you can register events.

You can update and maintain your hsql from standalone application and get data from again over this application to the tomcat. Then you dont have to worry about if there is a change or not.